Odoo 17 - Conditionally hide a field in parent view
Using Odoo 17, I've extended the res.partner model with some custom fields:
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    is_farmer = fields.Bool()
    ...

I'd like to conditionally hide the Tax ID field, based on if the is_farmer field is True or False.

I know I can hide the field using the position="attributes" syntax, as follows:
<record id="view_res_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

And I know I can control the visibility of a field individually using a Python expression in the invisible attribute:
<field name="vat" invisible="is_farmer"/>

But I can't seem to figure out how to combine this syntax to conditionally control the visibility of a field in an inherited view.
I've spent some time discussing with chatgpt, who suggests I should create a custom OWL component, but that really seems like overkill. Is this operation possible with the standard views?

Well this was easier than I thought in the end. I just needed to pass the expression as the value of the attribute node.
<xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">is_farmer</attribute>
</xpath>


Please mark the question as resolved then.
More options for anyone wondering:

you can use domains in the invisible attribute e.g: [('is_farmer', '=', True), ('id', 'not in', fake_or_outlier_farmers)]
Different case, but worth mentioning: another attribute for hiding a column in a one2many or many2many field: column_invisible https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/user_interface/view_architectures/generic_attribute_column_invisible.html?highlight=column_invisible

